# What is the meaning of a word or words surrounded by square brackets at the top of various file types?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, filesystems, configure

I see various file types with the following structure at the top of the file:
`[xxx]`

I work with AWS a lot and I see it often in their config files. For example regarding CFN-init, the config files that one is supposed to build on an EC2 instance resemble:

- in cfn-auto-reloader.conf:

  `[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
  trigger=...
  ...........`
- and in cfn-hup.conf:

  `[main]
  stack=...
  .........`

As a programmer, I'm used to `[]` being used to pinpoint array elements and various other language-specific things.

What does it mean for a configuration file or just a bash script when it is the only thing on a line?

Comment: Normally that would be some kind of section marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a section header.

It probably originates from the [INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), but other formats have adopted it (eg. [TOML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOML)).